# TSQL : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime, type-conversion

I had a query that was working but after importing again one table I see the following problem when converting a Varchar into DateTime.

I have the following problem when running the following query:

```
select FORMAT(convert (datetime,date)  ,   'ddMMyyyy')  from  kat.[dbo].[myTable]
```

If I try the following I see the same problem:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, date, 126) from kat.[dbo].[myTable]
```

The dates that I have in the main table follow the same format:

```
2017-09-01
```

EDit with Data Screenshot for the Format:

[image: DateFormat]

MAny thanks in advance,

Kat

Comment: So what format is the date in? Is it yyyy-MM-dd, yyyy-dd-MM or ddMMyyyy?

Comment: The date is as mentioned the following format : 2017-09-01 -> yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: You did not mention that, it could have been yyyy-dd-MM, especially since it is already different from your first mentioned format.

Comment: If I use select FORMAT(convert (datetime,date)  ,   'yyyy-MM-dd')  from  kat.[dbo].[myTable] I see the error too

Answer (score 0):

> The dates that I have in the main table follow the same format:
>
> ```
> 2017-09-01
> ```

There are some stings in your table that have different format.

Try to catch them with this code:

```
select *
from kat.[dbo].[myTable]
where dt not like '[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]';
```

In future, don't store datetime values as strings, use `datetime`/`date`.

**UPDATE**

So it's not true that your strings are like `'2017-09-01'`
Here is my example with your date:

```
declare @t table (dt varchar(20));
insert into @t values ('2017-09-01');

select *
from @t
where dt not like '[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]';
```

My code returns no rows because `'2017-09-01'` reflects the format you inicated, and if it returns all rows in your case, the format is different.

Comment: Hi sepupic, This query shows all the records of the table. Is there a better way to convert these strings into datetime?

Comment: So what is the problem? They miss a separator ot what? Can you give an example?

Comment: I updated my answer with your string, my code does not return the row '2017-09-01', so your strings are not of that format. I repeat my question, WHAT is real format of your strings?

Comment: varchar is a DATA TYPE, not a format. Format is yyyy-mm-dd, if belief to OP, but it is not REAL format of your strings. Why cannot you post an example of your string if you are not able to determine a format?

Comment: I have edited the main post with the screenshot of the data

Comment: Can you please execute select len(date) 
from kat.[dbo].[myTable]

Answer (score 0):

I actually think strings cannot be converted directly to dates (at least not when you use CAST)... Why not convert the string to an int first?

Assuming your column is named [Date], I would stick with:

```
SELECT
cast(DATEADD(DAY, cast([Date] as int), -2) as date) as [Date]
FROM kat.[dbo].[myTable]
```

If you have a different column name, here is the template:

```
SELECT
cast(DATEADD(DAY, cast([MyColumnName] as int), -2) as date) as [MyColumnName]
FROM kat.[dbo].[myTable]
```

Alternatively, I've also updated your code using CONVERT (which honestly I rarely every use so it could be wrong)

```
SELECT convert(datetime, convert(int, [Date]), 126) from kat.[dbo].[myTable]
```